# Formatting a data.frame with binary values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 4 columns and 4 rows. For simplicity, I changed it to numeric format. The schema is as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1,2,2,0),
                     b = c(2,1,2,2),
                     c = c(2,0,1,0),
                     d = c(0,2,1,1)),row.names=c(NA,-4L) ,class = "data.frame")
```

> ```
>   a b c d
> 1 1 2 2 0
> 2 2 1 2 2
> 3 2 0 1 0
> 4 0 2 1 1
> ```

I would like to change this data frame and obtain the following:

> ```
>    1     2
> 1  a     b/c
> 2  b     a/c/d
> 3  c     a
> 4  c/d   b
> ```

Is there a function or package I should look into? I have been doing lots of text processing in R recently. I'd appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Every row has 3 levels: c(0,1 2). I would like to turn these levels into columns. The actual file I am working on, has 0,1,2 but many more columns. So I am reshaping this into a data frame with 3 columns and turning the previous column names into values.

Comment: If a number appears more than once in a row, I'd write the associated column names and separate them by "/"

Comment: the data.frame isn't correct. the last row is 0,2,0,1.

Comment: just corrected it! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tapply` fun with some `row` and `col` indexes (stealing `df` from Ronak's answer):

```
tapply(
  colnames(df)[col(df)],
  list(row(df), unlist(df)),
  FUN=paste, collapse="/"
)[,-1]

#  1     2      
#1 "a"   "b/c"  
#2 "b"   "a/c/d"
#3 "c"   "a"    
#4 "c/d" "b"
```

Basically I'm taking one long vector representing each column name in `df`, and tabulating it by the combination of the `row` of `df`, and the original values in `df`.

Comment: This actually solves the second part of my problem where I have a second data.frame I am transforming using the first.

Answer (score 3):

One way with `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be to get data in long format, remove 0 values and paste the column names together for each row and value combination. Finally get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  group_by(row, value) %>%
  summarise(val = paste(name, collapse = "/")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = val)

#    row `1`   `2`  
#  <int> <chr> <chr>
#1     1 a     b/c  
#2     2 b     a/c/d
#3     3 c     a    
#4     4 c/d   b
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 0L), b = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 2L), 
c = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), d = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: This worked for the second part of the issue where I wanted to sort a second matrix based on this metadata df.